# Gradle FatJar task creating multiple MANIFEST.MF files

Tags: java, jar

When I run this FatJar/UberJar task, I end up with a .jar file whose META-INF\ folder contains two MANIFEST.MF files. One is the correct one with the attributes I inserted into the task definition, and the other simply contains "Manifest-Version: 1.0". **This causes a "Could not find or load main class" error when attempting to run the application** (I assume it is solely reading the first one and can't identify a main-class)

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
baseName = project.name

manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Synchronizer',
               'Main-Class': 'net.xxx.yyy.Main'
}     
     from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } 
     with jar 
}
```

---

MANIFEST.MF #1
Manifest-Version: 1.0

MANIFEST.MF #2:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Synchronizer
Main-Class: net.xxx.yyy.Main

Whats the reason for the duplicate Manifest?
I've tried excluding the MANIFEST.MF using

```
it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it).matching{exclude{it.path.contains == 'META-INF'}}  
it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it).matching{exclude{it.name.contains == 'MANIFEST'}}
```

*** These do exclude the child JAR META-INF folders and Manifest files, so I'm not sure where MANIFEST.MF #1 is coming from. It appears to be a default?

Answer (score 1):

On my version of gradle, I'm not getting 2 manifests with your code - I only end up with a single manifest containing Manifest-Version: 1.0 as you described.

The problem appears to be that your manifest closure isn't actually associated with the jar closure. The Jar task type assignement and "with jar" keyword don't do this for you. Therefore, it isn't recognized as the manifest file for the jar task. You should be able to fix this through one of these options:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name

    jar.manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Synchronizer',
               'Main-Class': 'net.xxx.yyy.Main'
    }     
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } with jar
}
```

Or, a cleaner way to write the same this would be to include the manifest and from closures in a jar closure:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name
    
    jar{
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Synchronizer',
                   'Main-Class': 'net.xxx.yyy.Main'
        }     
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } 
    }
}
```